# How to pull a specific scenario from a cucumber feature file using regex

Tags: java, regex, cucumber-java

I have a cucumber feature file that contains multiple scenarios and each has a different And.  I am using Java regex to parse the file and want to pull out a specific scenario based on the text in the And.

For example:

Feature: testing stuff

**Scenario:**

> lady swallows fly 
>       Given a lady 
>       and lady swallows a "fly"
>       then lady lives

**Scenario:**

> lady swallows spider Given a lady and lady swallows a "fly","spider"
>   then lady lives

**Scenario:**

> lady swallows everything 
>        Given a lady
>        and lady swallows a "fly","spider","cat","dog","cow"
>        then lady Dies

**Scenario:**

> lady swallows everything except the dog
>        Given a lady
>        and lady swallows a "fly","spider","cat","cow"
>        then lady Dies

I want to pull out the scenario that contains `dog` and dump it in a separate file. In my real life `dog=account number` and associates to multiple SQL extracts which are auto-loaded into a local database.  This is a single scenario, in a single feature file, which is one of hundreds.  So it's not a simple case of using `@run` at the top of the scenario.  I am actually extracting the scenario and associated files so they can be put in a sandbox.

The regex that I have so far is:

```
.*?dog.*Scen
```

but that selects from the first instance of Scenario into the Scenario beyond what I want.

Instead I want to pull out the group:

**Scenario:**

> lady swallows everything 
>        Given a lady
>        and lady swallows a "fly","spider","cat","dog","cow"
>        then lady Dies

Does anyone know how I can pull out that group?

Comment: Is each scenario contained in one continuous String? Or is there at least a "\n" delimiting them?

Answer (score 1):

If scenarios are delimited by \n, try with:

```
^[^\n]+\bdog\b[^\n]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jK7cJ5/5)

if it is contiuous string, try with:

```
(?=Scenario).+?\bdog\b.+?(?=Scenario|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jK7cJ5/4)

Comment: Add word boundaries and you're good to go.  These regexes will match strings that have the letters "dog" in it and not the word.